# Using Textbox Value to Change CSS on Button Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, border

I am trying to use the value from a user's textbox answer to change the CSS of an image. I want the image border width to change on a button click. This is what I have so far.

```
$('#submit').click(function () {
        var bv = $('#border').val();
        $('#pic').css('border-width', bv);
        });
```

- #submit is the button id, #border is the textbox id, and #pic is the image id.
  All advice is appreciated.

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: Looks fine, what seems to be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two corrections to your code

1. You have to initially provide other border parameters keeping `border-width` dynamic.
2. You have to concatenate "px" to your border-width variable

**JavaScript**

```
$('#submit').click(function () {
    var bv = $('#border').val();
    $('#pic').css('border-style', 'solid');
    $('#pic').css('border-color', 'black');
    $('#pic').css('border-width', bv+"px");
});
```

Here is a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/razx4edc/)

Comment: Worked! I found that you actually don't have to even add the "px" it works fine without. JS must jut assume pixels.

Answer (score 4):

Just try this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('#submit').click(function () {
            var bv = $('#border').val();
            $('#pic').css('border-style', 'solid');//You should use this line of code to get your requirement
            $('#pic').css('border-width', bv);
        });
    });
</script>

<input type="text" id="border">
<input type="button" id="submit" value="submit">
<img src="http://wallruru.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/White-Background-56.jpg" id="pic"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are forgetting to add a border color and border style to your image so when you add the border width nothing is shown.

This is what I try (and what I think you are doing) and is working fine.

**JS**

```
$(function(){
    $('#submit').click(function () {
        var bv = $('#border').val();
      $('#pic').css('border-width', bv);
    });
});
```

**CSS**

```
#pic {
  border: 0 black solid;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="border" />
<button id="submit">Click</button>

<img src="" id="pic">
```

Check out this [codepen](http://codepen.io/ianaya89/pen/RNNRPV).

Comment: This definitely works. I just prefer a method that doesn't require a generic css placeholder. I would just rather add a CSS with jquery if necessary. Thanks though.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with your code.
You might want to check or add a border style to the image.
You might be adding a border-width without having a border.

I tried this code and it worked perfectly after I added a border of

```
.imageName{
border:1px solid black;
}

$('#submit').click(function () {
   var bv = $('#border').val();
   $('#pic').css('border-width', bv);
   // you can also try this to make it smoother
   $('#pic').animate({'border-width': bv + 'px'});
});
```